# get_term_children for immediate children only (not grandchildren)

Tags: custom-taxonomy, terms, get-children, wp-error

I want to display term children of a custom taxonomy. Currently, I am able to do this using **get_term_children**, but using this, it displays children and grandchildren, I want to avoid this and make that only immediate children are shown.

This is what I have right now ( but it outputs children and grandchildren) :

```
<?php
$term_id = get_queried_object_id();
$taxonomy_name = 'mytaxname';

$termchildren = get_term_children( $term_id, $taxonomy_name );

foreach ( $termchildren as $child ) {
    $term = get_term_by( 'id', $child, $taxonomy_name );
    echo ' <div class="product-archive">';
        echo '<div class="post-title">
      <h3 class="product-name"><a href="' .get_term_link( $term, $taxonomy_name ). '">' .$term->name. '</a></h3>  
    </div>
  </div>';  }
?>
```

This is what I am trying to get to work so it shows only immediate children:

```
<?php
$term_id = get_queried_object_id(); 
$taxonomy_name = 'mytaxname';

$args = array('parent' => $term_id,'parent' => $term_id );
$termchildren = get_terms( $taxonomy_name, $args);

foreach ( $termchildren as $child ) {
    $term = get_term_by( 'id', $child, $taxonomy_name );
    echo ' <div class="product-archive">';
        echo '<div class="post-title">
      <h3 class="product-name"><a href="' .get_term_link( $term, $taxonomy_name ). '">' .$term->name. '</a></h3>  
    </div>
  </div>';  }
?>
```

This gives me a error :

**Catchable fatal error: Object of class WP_Error could not be converted to string in...**

What did I do wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use the [`get_terms()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms) function instead:

```
$term_children = get_terms(
    'mytaxname',
    array(
        'parent' => get_queried_object_id(),
    )
);

if ( ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ) {
    foreach ( $term_children as $child ) {
        echo '
            <div class="product-archive">
                <div class="post-title">
                    <h3 class="product-name"><a href="' . get_term_link( $child ) . '">' . $child->name . '</a></h3>
                </div>
            </div>
        ';
    }
}
```

`get_terms()` can return a WP_Error object, so you need to check that it didn't. It returns an array of term objects, so you no longer need to retrieve the objects with `get_term_by()`. Since `$child` is a term object, `get_term_link()` doesn't need the second parameter. [`get_terms()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms) has more options for the second parameter. You should take a look.

Comment: Since 4.5.0 the taxonomy should be included in the args array
$term_children = get_terms(
  array(
    'taxonomy' => 'mytaxname',
    'parent' => get_queried_object_id(),
  )
);